# best practice for Redis Node setup

Tags: node.js, express, redis

i have setup the redis client on the separate file

```
export function getRedisClient() {
  const port: number = redisConfig.port || 6379;
  const host = redisConfig.host;

  const client = redis.createClient(port, host, {
    no_ready_check: true,
    retry_strategy: function(options) {
      if (options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
        // a individual error
        return new Error('The server refused the connection');
      }
      if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
        // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
        // with a individual error
        return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
      }
      if (options.attempt > 10) {
        // End reconnecting with built in error
        return undefined;
      }
      // reconnect after
      return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
    },
  });

  client.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });

  client.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Redis Server Connected...');
  });

  return client;
}
```

the issue is it throw me `max number of clients reached`.

does calling the function create a new client each time i call the function?

if so can you guys suggest me a better practice of implementing the redis within the multiple service.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to create another client everytime. just create a single client and export it. import it whenever you want to use redis.

Comment: just only importing the client not the function.

Comment: @NikhilShrestha what you are doing is exporting the create client function. whenever you call that function, a new client will be created. this will make redis max connection reaches very soon because it's default to sth like 10k.